# Can I use single request, SRA, when implement inline-embedded GPT, DFP ad unit

Tags: google-dfp

I have some adunits that not are shown on every pages. Can I use both the standard-implementation and inline.

Is this code ok?

In head-element:

```
 googletag.cmd.push(function() {
   googletag.defineSlot('/34352841/ad1', [[250, 480], [250, 250]], 'div-gpt-ad-1474380277357-0').addService(googletag.pubads());       
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
    googletag.enableServices();


    });
```

In body:

```
  <!-- /34352841/ad1 -->
            <div id='div-gpt-ad-1474380277357-0'>
                <script>
                    googletag.cmd.push(function () { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1474380277357-0'); });
                </script>
            </div>

<!-- /34352842/ad2 -->
  <div id='div-gpt-ad-1474381227986-0'>
                <script>
                    googletag.cmd.push(function () {
googletag.defineSlot('/34352842/ad2', [[250, 480], [250, 250]], 'div-gpt-ad-1474381227986-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
 googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1474381227986-0'); });
                </script>
            </div>
```